# Split string and skip empty substrings

Tags: string, rust, iterator

I am learning Rust and discovered this problem:

I would like to split a string by a pattern and remove all cases where the resultin substring is empty.

Here is an example:

```
let s = "s,o,m,e,";
for elem in s.split(",").skip_while(|&x| x.is_empty()) {
    print!(" <{}> ", elem);
    //print!(" <{}>({}) ", elem, elem.is_empty());
}
```

But the result is the following:

```
 <s>  <o>  <m>  <e>  <>
```

My thoughts were: The struct `Split` returned by `split` implements `Iterator` which provides `skip_while`. IntelliSense told me the `x` in the closure is of type `&&str` so I would assume all the elements of the iterator (of type `&str`) which are empty to be omitted.

But it doesn't skip the empty substring.

I also tried to print the result of the `is_empty` function. It shows that the last slice is indeed empty. If I instead for the skip_while use `skip_while(|&x| x == "s")`, it correctly leaves out the `"s"` (printed with `is_empty` here):

```
 <o>(false)  <m>(false)  <e>(false)  <>(true)
```

So somehow the slice behaves differently in the iterator?

Why is that or where am I mistaken?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you only need to omit the 1 empty string at the end of input, just use [`split_terminator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_terminator) instead of `split`. This adapter is basically just like `split` but it treats the pattern argument as a terminator instead of a separator, so the empty string at the end of input is not considered a new element.

If you truly want to skip all the empty strings, keep reading.

---

[`skip_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip_while) is doing exactly as its documentation says (emphasis mine):

> `skip_while()` takes a closure as an argument. It will call this closure on each element of the iterator, and ignore elements until it returns `false`.
>
> **After `false` is returned, `skip_while()`'s job is over, and the rest of the elements are yielded.**

Filtering out all the elements that match a predicate, regardless of where they are in the sequence, is the job of [`filter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.filter):

```
let s = ",s,o,,m,e,";
for elem in s.split(",").filter(|&x| !x.is_empty()) {
    print!(" <{}> ", elem);
}
```

The above code will have the effect you wanted.

Note that the predicate to `filter` has the opposite meaning to `skip_while`: instead of returning `true` for elements that *should not* be yielded, it returns `true` for elements that *should* be yielded.

Answer (score 3):

[`skip_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.skip_while) *ignore elements until it returns false*, that is it will take all elements after the first non empty string in your case. For instance, given:

```
let s = ",,s,o,m,e,";
```

`skip_while` will ignore the first two empty strings but keep the last one:

```
let s = ",,s,o,m,e,";
for elem in s.split(",").skip_while(|&x| x.is_empty()) {
    print!(" <{}> ", elem);
}
```

Will print:

```
<s>  <o>  <m>  <e>  <>
```

For your case, it seems you just need `filter`:

```
let s = "s,o,m,e,";
for elem in s.split(",").filter(|&x| !x.is_empty()) {
    print!(" <{}> ", elem);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ebeab8dd9737df8cc398decb93e01c13)